# Hangfire client and server target different platforms, will it work?

Tags: hangfire

For example

- .netcore3.1 client schedules jobs
- .net472 server executes jobs
- shared code is inside a .netstandard2.0 library referenced by both server and client

Will it work at all? Is it safe?

Comment: Yes it should work. And yes it is safe ; as it is what netstandard 2.0 is designed for.
As long as you don't enqueue non netstandard2.0 code, it should be ok.